# Factoring out parts of an expression

Tags: symbolic, expression-manipulation

I'm looking to factor out the parts of a multiplication type of expression. For example for the expression:

$$20 e^{-t^2}\frac{t^2}{\sqrt{t^2+a}} erf(b+t)$$

I'd like to get a list in the form of:
$$\left\{ 20, \left\{t^2,\frac{1}{\sqrt{t^2+a}}, e^{-t^2}, erf(b+t) \right\} \right\}$$

Where only t is defined as a variable.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given

```
expression = (20*t^2*Erf[b + t])/(E^t^2*Sqrt[a + t^2])
```

[image]

can be achieved via replacement of the `Head`

```
List @@ expression
```

[image]

To find constant factors:

```
GatherBy[List @@ expression, NumberQ]
```

[image]

It is so because `Times` here is single `Head` for all first-level factors:

```
TreeForm[expression]
```

[image]

This also can prove to be useful:

```
FactorList[expression]
```

[image]

Comment: Okay, how do I group all the constants that do not depend on t into a single expression?

Comment: @user1581390 Do you mean go back? Not sure I understand.

Comment: I mean if the expression was $4 a b t$ I'd like to single out the constant part, in this case $4 a b$, because a and b do not depend on t.

Comment: @user1581390 I added an example above.